# "Start left" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could anybody help me to understand what "start left" means [here](https://securecodewarrior.com/become-a-secure-code-warrior)?

> *We get it. You're here because you want to **start left** but maybe you don't know where to begin? And we want you to **start left** because we want you to think and act with a secure coding mindset; without needing to become a security expert. We ultimately want you to ship secure code with confidence - and we can help you learn how to do it.*

Comment: Unless it is a special "secure coding" term, it does not make much sense to me. Ultimately, you could ask that company what they wanted to say.

Comment: I typed into Google *define start left* and it gave me this link, which looks relevant. Haven't read it yet. https://medium.com/@torstenvolk/starting-left-a-major-paradigm-shift-in-devops-ea25c900de9d#:~:text=%E2%80%9CStart%20left%E2%80%9D%20is%20based%20on,deployment%2C%20and%20day%202%20operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems what I've looked for. I didn't think it's a special term.